# tcpdump expression that capture port on one interface and another port on another interface?

Tags: tcpdump

I need to capture port 9090 on eth0 and port 8080 on lo (localhost or loopback). Can somebody shows me the tcpdump expression that can do that? I am current using

```
tcpdump -n -i any port 8080 or port 9090
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tcpdump -n -i any '(host ***ip of eth0*** and 9090) or (host 127.0.0.1 and 8080)'